# Изменение повторяющихся букв в слове

Tags: c++, строки

Мне нужно проверить наличие повторяющихся букв в слове, если буква повторяется, то заменить ее на 1, а если нет, то на 2.
Если я использую for(), то результат, к сожалению, зависит от последней буквы.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {  

string word;

char let1, let2;
int match = 0;
char bracket1('1');
char bracket2('2');
cout << "Write your word: ";
cin >> word;
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i)
{
    let1 = word[i];
    for (int j = 1; j < word.length(); ++j)
    {
        let2 = word[j];
        
            if (let1 == let2)
            {
                
                word[i] = bracket1;
                i++;
            }
            else {
                word[i] = bracket2;
            }
        }
    
   }
cout << word;
 }
```

Comment: Приложите пожалуйста ваш код, чтобы участники знали, что именно у вас не получается.

Comment: @umd, добавил код

Comment: за O(n) сортируем подсчетом, а потом смотрим на значение элемента массива, а потом вторым проходом заменяем
за O(nlogn) использую map <char, int>

Comment: @Neuro, благодарю, и я новичок, поэтому сложно понять, как сделать то, что вы указали